# sqLite: join subselect unique without using distinct becouse of performance reasons

Tags: sqlite

I have two joints but I do not want the same row again.
that works with **select distinct**.
but for performance reasons, I wanted to check that soon in the where clause with:
**and x.ROWID != w.ROWID**

but I get the following error:
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or **missing database (no such column: w.ROWID**)

Is that possible?

here the complete select:

```
select distinct substr(w.wordindexed, 1, 55), substr(w.word, 1, 15), w.wordreplacement
from Words w
       JOIN (SELECT x.ActionListId, x.wordindexed, x.word, x.wordreplacement
             from Words x
             where x.word like "%Hallo %"
               and x.ROWID != w.ROWID
             limit 1)
       JOIN (SELECT p.ActionListId, p.wordindexed, p.word, p.wordreplacement
             from Words p
             where p.word like "%Tool%"
               and p.ROWID != x.ROWID
             limit 1
            )
limit 5;
```

Example result:

```
3   HALLO VON _GLOBALACTIONLISTS\_GLOBAL.AHK    Hallo von _globalActionLists\_global.ahk    ""
6   HALLO WELT  Hallo Welt  ""
9   HALLO VON _GLOBALACTIONLISTS\_GLOBAL.AHK    Hallo von _globalActionLists\_global.ahk    ""
```

Example insert:

```
INSERT INTO Words (ActionListID, wordindexed, word, lineNr, count, worddescription, wordreplacement) VALUES (3, 'HALLO VON _GLOBALACTIONLISTS\_GLOBAL.AHK', 'Hallo von _globalActionLists\_global.ahk', 5, null, null, '');
INSERT INTO Words (ActionListID, wordindexed, word, lineNr, count, worddescription, wordreplacement) VALUES (3, 'STOP CHANGEING LIST|RR||AHK|G_CONFIG["LIST"]["CHANGE"]["STOPREXEXTITLE"]:="."', 'stop changeing list|rr||ahk|g_config["list"]["change"]["stopRexExTitle"]:="."', 7, null, null, '');
INSERT INTO Words (ActionListID, wordindexed, word, lineNr, count, worddescription, wordreplacement) VALUES (3, ' DONT CHANGEING LIST|RR||AHK|
', ' dont changeing list|rr||ahk|
', 9, null, null, '');
INSERT INTO Words (ActionListID, wordindexed, word, lineNr, count, worddescription, wordreplacement) VALUES (6, 'HALLO WELT ', 'Hallo Welt ', 9, null, null, '');
INSERT INTO Words (ActionListID, wordindexed, word, lineNr, count, worddescription, wordreplacement) VALUES (9, 'HALLO VON _GLOBALACTIONLISTS\_GLOBAL.AHK', 'Hallo von _globalActionLists\_global.ahk', 5, null, null, '');
```

the tabke:

```
create table Words
(
    ActionListID INTEGER not null,
    wordindexed TEXT not null,
    word TEXT not null,
    lineNr INTEGER,
    count INTEGER,
    worddescription TEXT,
    wordreplacement TEXT not null,
    primary key (ActionListID, word, wordreplacement)
)
;

create index WordIndex
    on Words (ActionListID, wordindexed)
;
```

Comment: Please add example data and expected result. There might be a whole better way to do what you are trying.

Comment: I think that's a good workaround: 

SELECT distinct *
FROM (SELECT distinct * FROM Words WHERE wordindexed LIKE "L%"

                                                            order by ROWID **asc** ) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT distinct *
      FROM Words
      WHERE wordindexed LIKE "%L%"
      order by ROWID **desc**
      ) t2;